# Homebrew PHP 8.2.1 uninstall

Tags: php, homebrew

I used Homebrew to install php. When I use php -v I get 8.2.1. When I use brew uninstall php@8.2.1 I get the response

```
No available formula with the name php@8.2.1. Did you mean php@8.1?
```

How do I get php 8.2.1 uninstalled from my mac?

Comment: `brew list`  should show which package is installed. `brew uninstall php@8.2`  could help

Comment: Thanks I new to the homebrew and did not think about list. It just says php.

Comment: And what happens if you run `brew uninstall php`?

Comment: I decided to keep the install.

Comment: just run this `cd /opt/homebrew/Cellar && rm -rf php`

Answer (score 2):

You need to check versions of PHP installed in your system

```
% brew ls --versions | grep '^php[ @]'
  
  // Expected result of few versions of PHP installed in your sys
  php@7.4 7.4.32
  php@8.2 8.2.1
```

Then if you need to remove anyone of them so you can done through this command `brew uninstall php@8.2`

For more detail information visit the links below:

- https://dev.to/micmath/manage-multiple-versions-of-php-with-homebrew-4dba
- https://php.watch/articles/php-8.3-install-upgrade-on-macos-homebrew#remove-old-versions